# Changing texture: unexpected scale results

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I can't get my head around what's going on here and I know I'm being stupid, but here's whats going on:

I have two images, one is 1024x768, one is 2048x1536.  They are "background" textures.  I'm trying to switch from one texture to the other:

```
CCSprite *bg = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"one.jpg"];
bg.scale = 0.5;
[self addChild:bg];
...
CCTexture2D* tex = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:two.jpg];
[bg setTexture: tex];
```

OK this is totally normal, the 2nd image fits perfectly into the same exact space and dimensions of the first, despite being a different resolution.  Now i'm adding a 2nd image so i can have the first one fade into the second one

```
CCSprite *newBG = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"two.jpg"];
newBG.scale = bg.scale;
[self addChild: newBG];
```

This however doesn't work, the image is twice as big as it should be.

So what exactly is happening here?  As best I can guess when a sprite is created from an image, the size of the sprite is set, and then any texture applied automatically scales to fit the space, and the 2nd doesn't work because the newly created sprite is using a different sized image?

Answer (score 0):

When you set a texture, you should also call

```
-(void) setTextureRect:(CGRect) rect;
```

to set its size. This is automatically called in `initWithTexture`, but not when you simply call `setTexture`. So, you assumption is right: the texture size is set when you init the sprite and not changes thereafter; but you can change it when you want to use a new texture.